# RDP connectivity/responsiveness test

Tags: remote-desktop

I want to write an app to test whether a Windows machine is responding correctly to **RDP (Remote Desktop)** - i.e. to check if the machine not only allows the connection, but is also responding normally, and is not hung or otherwise responding abnormally.

Is there a library or utility that I can use to do this? My searches turned up full `RDC clients`, but I'm hoping there's something out there at least offers an API for testing. I would most like to use Java or a scripting language to do this, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you have administrator access to these machines?

Answer (score 1):

Found this on [Experts Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Shell/Batch/Q_22627695.html):

```
use Net::Telnet ();
$t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 10, Prompt => '', Port >= 3389);
if($t->open("computer.name.or.ip")) {
    print "Connect successful\n";
}
else {
    print "Could not connect\n";
}
```

The idea was to attempt a connection and if it can't connect within 'x' amount of seconds, assume it isn't going to work.  Gets a bit more complicated if you're trying to see if a login for a specific user works or not, but this should at least get you started.

**NOTE**: As pointed out in the comments, the original solution left out the RDP port, so I included that in this...

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm looking for more than just telnet. I need the confirm that not only can the connection be handled, but that Remote Desktop is also responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some good answers in this question: [Programmatically create and launch and RDP session (without gui)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767035/programmatically-create-and-launch-and-rdp-session-without-gui)

Because RDP is a [constantly evolving proprietary protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol), i'm guessing there isn't some simple open-source code you can take and use. This leaves us with two possible paths to follow:

1. [Use Microsoft RDP ActiveX control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET) (on Windows)
2. Launch mstsc.exe and send keyboard events to it (also on Windows, using your favorite language)

For the second option, I suggest [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It is perfect for automating windows programs and comes with a powerful library. It also has a strong comunity behind it so you can find lots of useful scripts on the internet. I use it to control winamp (like 'i hate this song! delete it and move to next')(well, technically 'move to the next song and delete the previous' because you can't delete the file while in use but you get the idea). If you choose this path, i can help you with the script.