# Programmatically create and launch and RDP session (without gui)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, windows

I'd like to know if there is a way to create and launch a Remote Desktop Session on a Windows Server programmatically.

I'm trying to make an automatic tool to create Local Users and then launch the associate RDP session. I've already made LocalUser creation and adding them to Remote Desktop Users (using net.exe).
But I'm struck with the next step : create and launch user's rdp-session.
I don't know how to handle this problem without having the Remote Desktop Client Gui.

I'm working on a Windows Server 2003 and I'm using VS2008 with .NET 3.5.

Regards.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You want to create a remote desktop user on the lcoal machine, then launch a remote desktop session to the local machine?  Or from where?  By definition, you need more than one machine so how do you plan to do this programmatically from a single app?

Comment: @Mystere Man : The idea is to have an automatic way to create local users and the associate RDP session in order to get a closed executing context to provide him services

Comment: I'm still very vague about what you're trying to do.  You seem to want something different from what you're actually saying you want.  Could you please describe, in detail, exactly the scenario you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801093/create-windows-session-programmatically-from-console-or-windows-service/52801094#52801094 (@LorneCash 's answer was copied below and upvoted. that is now deleted - not sure why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Remote Desktop ActiveX control to connect, you would need to host it in a Form but the form wouldn't need to be visible. For an example see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RemoteDesktop_CSharpNET.aspx

Answer (score 17):

You can call mstsc.exe and pass parameters on the command line to tell it what to connect to.

[mstsc.exe documentation on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc)

Comment: I couldn't find a way to pass username or password with the command line so this wasn't a solution for me but it may work for others who don't want it fully automated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I've found that an option on the server is needed to enable Terminal Service autologin.

> 1. On the Terminal Server, click Start, point to Programs, point to
>      Administrative Tools, and then click
>      Terminal Server Connection
>      Configuration.
> 2. Double-click the rdp-tcp connection, and then click Advanced.
>      If you want to modify properties for
>      ICA clients, double-click the ica-rdp
>      connection instead, and then click
>      Properties.
> 3. In the AutoLogon section, click to clear the Prompt for Password check
>      box.
> 4. Click OK, click OK, and then click Exit on the Connection menu.

source : support.microsoft.com/kb/260711

After that, I've made something based on this project :
codeproject.com/KB/cs/RemoteDesktop_CSharpNET.aspx
For what I've tested, I think it's not possible to omit an RDP Client connection (MsTscLib or mstsc.exe)
I've got something working but it's certainly bad style. I'm using ActiveX Component Events to know the result of the connection. Ie : OnLogonError and OnLoginComplete.

here my source : 
http://codepaste.net/uiuuxc

I'm awaiting your comments.

Comment: source link is 404